# Return the list of Deleted row in myBatis

Tags: mysql, mybatis

**I want to return the list of deleted row details to the controller**

```
<delete id = "delete-record", parameter-type = "hash-map">
DELETE FROM <Table Name>
WHERE id = #{id};

</delete>
```

in the above segment I cannot find any return type

Answer (score 2):

Use `RETURNING` clause and `select` mapping with `flushCache`:

```
<select id="removeSomeStuff" parameterType="map" resultType="WhateverType" flushCache="true">
    delete from some_stuff where id = #{id}
    RETURNING *
</select>
```

The above query returns the result set equivalent to `select * from some_stuff` and you can use any mapping option (e.g. `resultMap` or `resultType`) to get objects.

Answer (score 0):

if you using Mariadb > 10.0.5 then you can use the Keyword **RETURNING** like:

```
DELETE FROM `data` 
WHERE `timestamp` BETWEEN '2019-03-08 02:11:45' AND '2019-03-18 03:20:45'
RETURNING id,`name`,`state`;
```

see: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/delete/

**Sample**

```
MariaDB [test]> CREATE TABLE `data` (
    ->   `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `timestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `name` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `state` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.023 sec)

MariaDB [test]> INSERT INTO `data` (`id`, `timestamp`, `name`, `state`)
    -> VALUES
    -> (1, '2019-03-07 11:16:32', 'Light_A', 0),
    -> (2, '2019-03-07 12:36:32', 'Light_A', 1),
    -> (3, '2019-03-07 13:15:12', 'Light_A', 0),
    -> (4, '2019-03-08 02:11:45', 'Light_A', 1),
    -> (5, '2019-03-08 02:18:45', 'Light_A', 1),
    -> (6, '2019-03-08 02:22:45', 'Light_A', 0),
    -> (7, '2019-03-18 03:14:45', 'Light_B', 0),
    -> (8, '2019-03-18 03:16:45', 'Light_B', 1),
    -> (9, '2019-03-18 03:18:45', 'Light_B', 1),
    -> (10, '2019-03-18 03:20:45', 'Light_B', 0),
    -> (11, '2019-03-19 17:20:12', 'Light_B', 0),
    -> (12, '2019-03-19 17:22:12', 'Light_B', 1),
    -> (13, '2019-03-19 17:23:12', 'Light_B', 0);
Query OK, 13 rows affected (0.009 sec)
Records: 13  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

**now DELETE**

```
MariaDB [test]> DELETE FROM `data` WHERE
`timestamp` BETWEEN '2019-03-08 02:11:45' AND '2019-03-18 03:20:45'
RETURNING id,`name`,`state`;
+----+---------+-------+
| id | name    | state |
+----+---------+-------+
|  4 | Light_A |     1 |
|  5 | Light_A |     1 |
|  6 | Light_A |     0 |
|  7 | Light_B |     0 |
|  8 | Light_B |     1 |
|  9 | Light_B |     1 |
| 10 | Light_B |     0 |
+----+---------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [test]>
```

Answer (score -1):

mybatis can help us do this thing automatically

```xml
<delete id="deleteDemo">
  DELETE FROM Table_Name
  WHERE ID = #{id}
</delete>
```

see Mapper.java like this:

```java
int deleteDemo(@Param("id") String id);
```

it's will return number of records affected.

mybatis can find this number from jdbc.

`<update>` is the same way.

if you want to improve a little, learn about `useAffectedRows` in jdbc

Comment: He is asking **what** gets delete but you are saying **how many**.